# Can't open https://graph.facebook.com/

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, ssl, https

Whatever I have tried I cannot navigate to "*https://graph.facebook.com/...*" neither from the web-browser, or from web-client.

Every time I try to debug, I receive an error related to the certificate on targeting domain!

I even tried:

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/wFace-windows-phone-7-facebook-integration-part-1.aspx

and it doesn't work on my VS2010 debugger anymore.

But did worked before for a few weeks both with emulator and WP7 device.

At the same time, url's like "*http://graph.facebook.com/...*" are working without any problem.

Did someone experience this similar problem?

Or somebody with good idea to solve this particular problem?!

Answer (score 1):

1. Check [the list of supported SSL Certificates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521150%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).
2. [HowTo install](http://joymonscode.blogspot.com/2011/11/installing-ssl-certificates-to-windows.html) SSL Cert to WP7 Emulator

Comment: Thank's for the answer! But another thing is which certificate should i search for..

Comment: Hm, facebook uses DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA. This cert is in the list of supported certificates.

Comment: No. This certificate is already installed. Interested thing is that I can successfuly reach that Url from al browser but not from IE(9) and neither from VS2010. There must be something about Internet options...

Comment: I did it in totaly different way!!!!!!!!!!!!! If anybody wants to know how, contact me..............

Comment: You'd better to post the way you solve the problem here (as an answer), and accept it.